# Lync 2013 SDK - Join Conference & Connect AVModality when "Join meeting audio from" setting set to "Do not join audio"

Tags: audio, lync, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk, conference

I'm rather new to the Lync 2013 SDK (been using it for a couple weeks now) and have been able to figure out mostly everything I need except for this...

When I'm joining a conference (using ConversationManager.JoinConference()) it joins fine. However, in certain cases (not all), I want to then connect the AVModality on the conference. Sometimes it works, sometimes it just sits in "Connecting" and never connects (even though I've called EndConnect).

What I've found is the setting in Skype's Options -> Skype Meetings -> Joining conference calls section, seems to override my code. Maybe a race condition?

When the setting is "Do not join audio" and "Before I join meetings, ask me which audio device I want to use" is NOT CHECKED (meaning I get no prompt when joining): the conference joins, the AVModality goes Disconnected -> Connecting -> Disconnected. Then my code triggers a BeginConnect and the AVModality goes Disconnected -> Connecting - and never resolves (sometimes I get a fast busy tone audio sound).

When the "Before I join meetings, ask me which audio device I want to use" IS CHECKED (meaning I get the prompt): the conference joins, the prompt asks how to connect, if I select Skype for business - it connects audio fine (expected). Interestingly, if I hang up the call using the Lync UI (AVModality goes to Disconnected), it then immediately connects back again (assuming my BeginConnect doing this).

Here's where it gets really convoluted:
If I call BeginConnect when the state is Connecting on the AVmodality within the ModalityStateChanged event handler... the following happens:
Conference joins, prompt asks me how to connect (AVmodality state is "Connecting" at this point until a decision is made on the prompt) - this means my BeginConnect fires. Then if I choose "Do not join audio" in the prompt... the AVModality status goes Connecting -> Disconnected -> Connecting -> Joining -> Connected. So - my BeginConnect is already in progress and still works in this case so long as it fires BEFORE the selection of "Do not join audio".

So I'm wondering if the "Do not join audio" selection (whether with or without the prompt) actually sets some other properties on something which prevents the AVModality from being connected after that point without doing some additional hocus pocus? If so - I'd like to know the additional hocus pocus I need to perform :)

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

It's come down to this... whether the conference joining does join the audio or not - I've handled every scenario except one, which I still can't figure out:
1. I need the conference audio to be joined, but the user selects to NOT join the audio (either on the prompt, or from the Skype options settings).

In this case - I have added an event handler to the modality state change event, and when the NewState == Disconnected, I trigger a BeginConnect on the modality itself. This works fine. Within the callback, I have the EndConnect call. However - the AVModality state continues to stay in "Connecting" and never resolves to being connected. On the UI - it shows the audio buttons, but all grayed out (like normal when it's connecting). I'm not sure how to make it finish connecting?

Here's a snippet of code:

```
    if (merge)
            {
                myHandler = delegate (object sender1, ModalityStateChangedEventArgs e1)
                {
                    AVModality avModality = (AVModality)sender1;
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.confConvo = avModality.Conversation;
                    if (e1.NewState == ModalityState.Connected)
                    {                            
                        DialNumberInSkype(meetingInfo);
                        avModality.ModalityStateChanged -= myHandler;
                    }
                    if (e1.NewState == ModalityState.Disconnected)
                    {
                        object[] asyncState = { avModality, "CONNECT" };
                        avModality.BeginConnect((ar) =>
                        {
                            avModality.EndConnect(ar);
                            DialNumberInSkype(meetingInfo);
                        }, asyncState);
                        avModality.ModalityStateChanged -= myHandler;
                    }
                };
            }
```

**EDIT:**
For some reason, I'm not able to add a comment right now...

I tried setting the endpoint as you suggested. However, I get an ArgumentException error "Value does not fall within the expected range." So I tried hardcoding the uri value in the CreateContactEndpoint to "sip:my_login@domain.com" (except real value of course) - and got the same ArgumentException error. I added a breakpoint before this and was able to see the value for the avModality.Endpoint - and it is actually set to me the entire time... it's not null or unset when I'm trying to call BeginConnect.

Answer (score 0):

When JoinConference() is invoked audio modality will be connected even without explicitly invoking BeginConnect().

When prompt asking for audio device selection is shown(when ask before join option is set in skype) conversation property ConferenceEscalationProgress will be having value AwaitingJoinDialogResponse.

Setting conversation property ConferenceJoinDialogCompleted as true will initiate Modality connection even though the prompt is not closed.

**Edited**

If do not join audio is selected, modality will be disconnected, at this point you are trying to invoke BeginConnect(). Try setting modality endpoint before invoking BeginConnect().

```
conversation.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].Endpoint = lyncClient.Self.Contact.CreateContactEndpoint(lyncClient.Self.Contact.Uri);
```

Comment: First - thanks for the reply!

I've been tracking this property recently in my testing ... this helps explain some behavior. However, if the setting is such that the prompt doesn't show, I've noticed that the ConferenceJoinDialogCompleted property is immediately set to True - and the AVModality goes Disconnected -> Connecting -> Disconnected upon joining. After this occurs, I've not been able to find any way to connect the AVModality successfully...?

Comment: Prompt is to select the audio endpoint uri, i.e the AV Modality endpoint uri. If you select audio as skype endpoint, uri will remain as sip:yourusername@domain.com, if you select telephone number then endpoint uri will be "tel:your phone number". Is there any warning in UI?

Comment: Sorry for the long time period - had some other more pressing issues come up in the meantime. I'll write a new response below...

Comment: Hi Scott please check edited answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work - please check my edited answer I added for more details

Comment: Hey Kannan, let me know if you have any more thoughts please!

Comment: Hi Scott, I tried reproducing the scenario, one thing that i noticed is when AV Modality is Disconnected after Do not Join audio is selected modality properties (like audio capture device) are not set that may be the reason BeginConnect() is not giving the result when you try to connect.

Comment: Interesting. Are you referring to the avmodality itself or the audio channel?

Comment: i mean the AV modality properties.